# Multiple non-url parameters in WCF post request

Tags: javascript, wcf, post

I have a WCF service like this:

```
public IEnumerable<int> AddProperty(string productId, string propertyClass, Property properties)
```

and I called it with the following data:

```
{
    "Class":{"Name":"aoeu","Restricted":false,"Type":"ScalarProperty"},
    "DisplayName":"aoeu",
    "Id":"560",
    "Value":"aoeu"
}
```

and it worked fine. Now I want to add another `Property` to the service like this:

```
public IEnumerable<int> AddProperty(string productId, string propertyClass, Property properties, Property properties2)
```

What data should I pass? I tried this:

```
{
    properties: {
        "Class":{"Name":"aoeu","Restricted":false,"Type":"ScalarProperty"},
        "DisplayName":"aoeu",
        "Id":"560",
        "Value":"aoeu"
    },
    properties2: {
        "Class":{"Name":"aoeu","Restricted":false,"Type":"ScalarProperty"},
        "DisplayName":"aoeu",
        "Id":"560",
        "Value":"aoeu"
    }
}
```

but it didn't work! I tried some different ways, but they all didn't work :( Any help?

Comment: In the first example that works, how are you passing `productId` and `propertyClass`? Your `properties2` should be on the same level as those

Comment: productId and propertyClass are passed as URL parameters, but I want to be able to pass properties2 in POST's body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the above as shown:

```
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,UriTemplate = "MultipleProperties?productId={productId}&propertyClass={propertyClass}")]    
public IEnumerable<int> AddProperty(string productId, string propertyClass, Property properties, Property properties2)
```

You need to set the body style to Wrapped when you want to serialize more than 1 object as part of a POST requst.

Now assuming your Property class is defined as below:

```
[DataContract]
    public class Property
    {
        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
```

The raw Http request would look like:

```
POST http://locahost/XMLService/Service1.svc/AddProperty?productId=1&propertyClass=2 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 134

{"properties": {"boolvalue": "true", "stringvalue": "str"}, "properties2" :{"boolvalue": "true", "stringvalue":"str2"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you do it this way?

```
public IEnumerable<int> AddProperty(string productId, string propertyClass, Property[] properties);
```

and then

```
[ 
    { 
        "Class":{"Name":"aoeu","Restricted":false,"Type":"ScalarProperty"}, 
        "DisplayName":"aoeu", 
        "Id":"560", 
        "Value":"aoeu" 
    }, 
    { 
        "Class":{"Name":"aoeu","Restricted":false,"Type":"ScalarProperty"}, 
        "DisplayName":"aoeu", 
        "Id":"560", 
        "Value":"aoeu" 
    } 
]
```

I'm making the assumption you've only shown us the property code rather than productId, propertyClass etc as I cant see them?

Comment: I can do that, but this is not what I want. I want to be able to pass multiple parameters via the POST body.